# How to create edit/update actions for model to display in partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have a model :folder that belongs to :user and renders each folder on the homepage when a user is logged in. For each folder, there should be an 'edit' link to update the folder's parameters. Here's what I have so far (already have a edit form for :folder):

Edit/Update actions in the folders_controller:

```
def edit
  @folder = Folder.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @folder = Folder.find(params[:id])
  if @folder.update_attributes(folder_params)
    flash[:success] = "Folder updated"
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

Here is where I am having a problem. This is a snippet of the :folder partial that renders on the homepage:

```
<% if current_user?(folder.user) %>
  <%= link_to "edit", edit_folder_path(@folder) %> |
  <%= link_to "delete", folder, method: :delete,
                        data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
<% end %>
```

If a current user of the folder is logged in, there should be an edit and delete link visible. However, I am receiving this error:

**ActionController::UrlGenerationError in StaticPagesController#home**

**No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"folders", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]**

But when I replace

```
<%= link_to "edit", edit_folder_path(@folder) %>
```

with

```
<%= link_to "edit", edit_folder_path(id: 61 (or some random folder id) %>
```

It renders fine but doesn't update. How can I fix this? Do I have to create an instance variable for my Homepage controller? And if so, what do I put?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but in your controller you would better replace `Folder.find` with `current_user.folders.find`, otherwise anyone can update any folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a simple typo. Instead of `@folder`, you should use `folder`. In other words:

```
<%= link_to "edit", edit_folder_path(folder) %>
```

The `@folder` variable doesn't exist, hence the `nil` error message.